# Fotorama: height for slides with html content

Tags: fotorama

this is my first question on Stackoverflow, I hope it makes sense :)

I need to create a swipeable image gallery with html content in each slide (text, images, external links, social network buttons etc) and full screen option.
Fotorama is the best solution I have found, I am a very big fan of it :)

However, I am finding it difficult to fit the html content in the gallery, as it gets cropped to the height of the first image.

I need the image to be in the html, not a background image. And I need all the content to be visible both in the normal mode and in the full screen mode. The text can vary in length and the images in size, so I cannot give the gallery a fixed height.

Does it make sense? 
I couldn't find a similar question asked already, so if you have any idea please let me know!
Thanks :)

This is the simplified code of what I have done so far, any comment is more than welcome!

```
<div class="fotorama" data-allowfullscreen="true" data-nav="thumbs" data-click="false"  data-width="100%">
<div data-thumb="image-01.jpg" id="slide1">
    <h2>Title 01</h2>
    <img src="image-01.jpg" width="100%">
    <div class="content">                        
        <p>Blah blah blah</p>
        <div class="photoShare">
            <h6>Share</h6>
            <!-- Social Network Buttons -->
        </div>
        <div class="buyThisPhoto">
            <!-- Buy this photo link -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- etc -->
```

Update: 
I am working on possibe solution, using the API. Seems to work but any suggestion for improvement is welcome :)

```
$(function () {    
var $fotoramaDiv = $('#fotorama').fotorama();    
var fotorama = $fotoramaDiv.data('fotorama');
$('.fotorama').on('fotorama:ready ' + 'fotorama:show ' + 'fotorama:load ', function () {             
        var currentContainer = $(".fotorama__active").children('div'); 
        var newHeight = /* calculate the height by adding up the heights of the elements contained in currentContainer */;       
        fotorama.resize({
            height: newHeight
        });
      }).fotorama();
});
```

Comment: It is possible to extend Fotorama to have flexible height that depends on content of the frame: http://jsfiddle.net/XxrQV/3/

But I have no idea how to bring this flexibility to the fullscreen. Have you?

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot for your reply. Is there something I missed, as it doesn't seem to work for me?

Comment: However, no, the fullscreen version is still an issue. I am trying to make at least one work as requested :)

Comment: Sorry, ignore previous comment, it does work indeed. The very first frame was cropped to the height of the image, but that was easily fixed. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: They are happy with the gallery. Thanks again!

I enquired about the fullscreen version (with no thumbnails). 
I have been asked if the content can be fit all in the screen (calculating the height of the content). Do you think this can be done without too much pain?